# the compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a jre 18 is used

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, warnings, compiler-warnings

VS Code reported the warning that `"the compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a jre 18 is used"` and I don't know how to solve it. I'm searching for more information but I can't find anything about this problem, I need help to solve it.

Comment: Make sure you have `JDK` available that matches your `JRE`.

Comment: Did you ever find a way for Eclipse to keep these changes to your version?

Answer (score 0):

**Here are three modification methods:**

1. Please set the `pom.xml` file for the maven project

```xml
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

2. Modify the `.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file under the Java project

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=18
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=18
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportPreviewFeatures=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=18
```

3. Add the following in `settings.json`

```json
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home":"your_path_to_jdk18"
```

Comment: Eclipse keeps overwriting these with the old values even if I save outside of Eclipse and Eclipse isn't running.